# using GCM to open a spicific page in tha pp

Tags: android

i want to make when the user click on the GCM notification it open the app with a specific action, is that possible and also, how can i make when i open any URL from any mobile that installed the app and that URL from my app site it open the app with the specific article related to that URL

i send to google 3 things

```
array("title" => '',"description" => '',"link" => '')
```

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/

Comment: GCM appear in your notifications?

Answer (score 1):

implement deep linking concept it will be helpfull in mny other scenarios
[Deep linking](https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/android/app)

Answer (score 1):

when you create notification you put intent into it which starts you main activity. also you can put bundle into this intent and get it in main activity when it will starts. than handle content and setup activity stack and open it